# Concavity of Logistic Growth Function Above Carrying Capacity

Tags: derivatives, exponential-function, graphing-functions

The derivative of logistic growth of a population over time is
$$\frac{dP}{dt} = 5P - 0.002P^2$$

When I take the second derivative I end up with $5 - 0.004P$.

This means for populations above 1250, the curve is concave down, but below 1250 the curve is concave up. However above the carrying capacity (2500), the curve should be concave up.

Why is the second derivative wrong in showing that for populations above 1250, the graph is concave down?

Comment: As you approach carrying capacity, the (positive) first derivative heads to 0.  The second derivative then is negative, and the curve is concave.

Comment: I understand, but when I plug in a population above 2500 in the second derivative equation, I get a negative number indicating that the concavity of the graph is negative when it should be positive.

Comment: Ususally, you don't have initial conditions greater than the carrying capacity.  Not that it can't happen.  You should get a curve that asymptotically approaches the carrying capacity.  Regarding your calculation of the second derivative, to find the second derivative, you need to take the derivative with respect to $t,$ not with respect to $P.$  You need to apply the chain rule.  i.e.  $P'' = (5 - 0.004P)(5P-0.002P^2)$   This should give you the positive sign on the second derivative you are looking for.

Comment: Ok. That makes sense, I forgot to do that. Thanks and if you want to post the comment as an answer I will be happy to accept it.